# How to close InputStream which fed into Response(jax.rs)

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, cxf

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}/content")
@Produces({ "application/octet-stream" })
public Response getDocumentContentById(@PathParam("id") String docId) {

    InputStream is = getDocumentStream(); // some method which gives stream
    ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(is);
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    return responseBuilder.build();

}
```

Here how can I close the InputStream is ? If something(jax.rs) closes automatically. Please give me some information. Thank you.

Comment: All Java object serialization is handle with `MessageBodyWriter`s. The JAX-RS implementation should have one specifically for `InputStream`. Do some debug tracing to find out which one CXF uses, then go to the source code and look at its `writeTo` method. I would do it, but I don't work with CXF. If you look at Jersey's [`InputStreamProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/InputStreamProvider.java#L63), you will see that it does close the stream. I imagine CXF would do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're wanting to stream a custom response, the most reliable way I've found is to return an object that contains the `InputStream` (or which can obtain the stream in some other way at some point), and to define a `MessageBodyWriter` provider that will do the actual streaming at the right time.

For example, [this code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-taverna-server/blob/master/taverna-server-webapp/src/main/java/org/apache/taverna/server/master/rest/handler/ZipStreamHandler.java) is part of Apache Taverna, and it streams back the zipped contents of a directory. All that the main code needs to do to use it is to return a `ZipStream` as the response (which can be packaged in a `Response` or not) and to ensure that it is dealing with returning the `application/zip` content type. The final point to note is that since this is dealing with CXF, you need to manually register the provider; unlike with Glassfish, they are not automatically picked up. This is a good thing in sophisticated scenarios, but it does mean that you need to do the registration.